# Connection from breadboard to stripboard

Tags: circuit-analysis, breadboard, stripboard

I already have my circuit placed on breadboard. Now I need to transfer it on stripboard. My question is I can just transfer the exact same connection and placement on stripboard right? I don't need to add up or adjust the circuit right?

[image]

this is my circuit on breadboard.

[image: my circuit on stripboard]

this is my circuit on stripboard.

Comment: Does the stripboard have traces in it like a breadboard? If it does and you copied it exactly then yes, it would work. Otherwise it would not be to difficult to create traces on the bottom with some solder.

Comment: @catsarethebest Stripboard has continuous strips of copper on each row of pins, not divided in two like a breadboard, and not fully separated like perfboard. It's likely some copper will have to be cut to transfer a circuit from breadboard to stripboard.

Comment: @Hearth his breadboard creation is all on one side of the breadboard

Comment: There are boards that you can buy that have the exact same connection layout as solderless breadboards. Although I normally wouldn't recommend Amazon, if you search for "solderable breadboard" on Amazozn, you will find what I am referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I recognize now that stripboard has traces. Judging by how his breadboard creation was all on one side of the breadboard he should not need to cut any traces on the board. To answer the OPs question, this should work just fine (though if you are going to solder it into the stripboard, you should use some solid wire and not those jumper wires).

I am answering this on the basis that the perfboard does not have any traces, like every perfboard I have ever had. You are not able to get this circuit to work unless you were planning on having sketchy >50GΏ resistors between all the wires. In order to get this to work you must create a solder and/or wire bridge between the wires you want to connect. If you want it to be more reliable than I would highly suggest using some solid core 22awg insulated wire instead of the breadboard hookup wires. Those are meant for prototyping and not for building a final design. I have learned the hard way that soldering those dupont breadboard hookup wires leads to the wires snapping off quickly.

Comment: "stripboard" has traces.

Comment: Oh ok, I did not know that, thanks for telling me. His thing should work just fine. I will edit this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is months late, but I just recently built up a simple strip board, and I had one trace I had to cut just beyond each solder point because the signal was seeing reflections that were sufficient to corrupt data.

The full strip board was about three times longer than the once inch trace that was left after it was cut.

I had never encountered that before, but looking at the signal at its end point with an oscilloscope, you could see the ringing. Trimming the trace was easy, and solved the problem. I could have added a termination resistor to damp it, trimming was easier.

I know, strip board is not ideal for high speed signals, but this was just a prototype. It served its purpose.